# Download .msg files in client side Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a server containing multiple .msg files
I want to enable the user to download them in the client side using the following code:

```
const download = (fileName) => {
        var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
        FileSaver.saveAs(constants.filesUploadUrl + fileName, fileName);
    }
```

The download is working fine with all data types except .msg files
It gives me "Failed - No file"
[image]

Is there a way to enable downloading .msg files in client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to convert the content type into "application/vnd.ms-outlook"
As it wasn't recognized via Google chrome as .msg

My backend ASP.Net Core
Code for mapping MIME Type:

```
 }
            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings[".msg"] = "application/vnd.ms-outlook";
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
```